# How to pass an argument and file variable to vs code

Tags: windows-registry, visual-studio-code

For certain reasons that I don't fully understand we have to start VSCode with the `--in-process-gpu` flag on our work laptops (without the tag it opens the outline of the window and then pegs the CPU out indefinitely). Not a problem to add to the shortcut used by the start menu and we were able to update the `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\shell\VSCode\command` registry entry with `"C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" " --in-process-gpu" "%V"` to get the *Open With Code* directory context to work.

What I can't figure out is how to update the `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\VSCode\command` registry entry to get the file context variant to work. By default it's set to `"C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" "%1"` but changing it to something like `"C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" " --in-process-gpu " "%1"`  just opens a new file called *--in-process-gpu* along with the file I right-clicked on. Changing the order and trying some of the other variables like `%V` and `%L` didn't make a difference.

Appreciate guidance on how to get the command to see the flag as a flag and not another file.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotes around your flag.

Here is my value (which works fine for me):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\*\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe\" --in-process-gpu \"%1\""
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response but it didn't work, unfortunately. It just opens Code with the previously opened files. Not with the file that was right-clicked.

Comment: Use the system internals process monitor and look at the command line that was used to launch the process.  You should be able to narrow down the cause by using it.

Comment: It's opening a blank window (or the previously opened files) with this command:

`Parent PID: 14396, Command line: "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" --in-process-gpu "C:\Users\myusername\Documents\WORK\21. projectname\gc_code\gcmgmt\builder\Dockerfile", Current directory: c:\users\myusername\documents\work\21. projectname\gc_code\gcmgmt\builder\,`